# Arduino Nano clone doesn't fit into breadboard. How can I work around this?

Tags: arduino-nano, prototype

I have bought an arduino nano clone (called funduino) and upon trying to place it into my breadboard to work with it I realised that the pins do not line up with the holes on the breadboard so I simply can't use the funduino...

[image: Nano Clone]

Does anyone have any recommendations on how I can get around this?

Comment: Is it your breadboard or the funduino that doesn't have the 0.1inch pitch ;)

I see that the last pin (VIN?) is a little bent, you might check if any of the pins is a little of and bend it back in line. Then it should work, given they're both 0.1inch pitch (but I don't see why not).

Comment: What is a 0.1inch pitch?

Comment: 0.254 centimeters pin spacing. The space between two pins.

Comment: Have you tried just patience and persistence?  Some of mine feel tight but in the end they go in.  (Bent pins can be unsoldered and new pins can be put in, if you need to do so, but it is best not to push too hard until you are convinced it can be made to work)

Comment: bruh I've forgot how to even use my arduino I've not touched it in that long, thanks for the reply though lol

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use [these female to female jumper](https://www.adafruit.com/product/266) wires and [these headers](https://www.adafruit.com/products/400) and hook up the board and breadboard like this:

[image]

Note, the square female cable ends may not fit closer than 0.1 inches on center.

A more compact and (possibly) mechanically difficult solution may be implemented using wire-wrap sockets.  You may be able to leave the sockets intact and deform the pins to match the breadboard.  Or you may need to remove the pins from the plastic in order to accommodate your (different) Nano:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about that initially, I just didn't want to spend anymore money/ wait for them to arrive haha, would you recommend me attempting to disfigure the device at all?

Comment: I thought the Nano's pins were already 0.1 inch on center.  So a picture of why this board doesn't fit into your breadboard would be helpful.  W/o that, I can only guess.  But guessing, what I would do is not disfigure the Nano's pins but to plug it into a "hacked" wire wrap socket(s) (long stiff pins) and disfigure the socket such that it can plug into the breadboard.

Comment: These seems much simpler than your current answer. Update it and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Found a good wirewrap pin picture. I'll update answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the same issue, I use mine with a miniature breadboard:

[image]

Comment: Is there a link to that breadboard type? I have found one on bitsbox that looks similar but I'm not sure if it will fit

Comment: [Image](http://www.bitsbox.co.uk/images/small/connects/CN338.jpg)

Comment: How is that a help?  These have exactly the same pin spacing as larger breadboards.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-wholesale-10pcs-lot-SYB-170-Mini-Solderless-Prototype-Experiment-Test-Breadboard-170-Tie-points/2036052089.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.113.Ut6D8y&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_8,searchweb201602_2_10017_10021_507_10022_10020_10009_10008_10018_10019_101,searchweb201603_9&btsid=33de1495-5588-470c-91f2-388b0da64103) to the above breadboard. And the spacing is different, at least when I compare it to my standard size breadboard.

Comment: I use these, and they work well.  They are available from the usual sources, and with US suppliers can be on your workbench in 3-4 days.